# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/client/config/ClientConfig RestFul

Tags: rest, jar, client

My Restful web service and client work fine. I build client become jar file. But I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/client/config/ClientConfig
    at ass.main(ass.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: It seams that your ClientConfig is not located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you miss the `jersey-client.jar` in your classpath. Download and add it to your classpath.

Comment: I solve this problem with the way add full jersey-1.9 library. Thanks for your help